# Query returns more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression although I am positive it is just one

Tags: postgresql

I have a payment table with one row is a payment record per an account. The first payment is usually the downpayment.
What I need is to add a column which flags 1 if it is the first payment per an account and 0 if it is not. I came up with the ugly query but it throws an error about duplicated rows.

```
SELECT o.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN o.concat = (SELECT DISTINCT ac.id 
                                          || '-' 
                                          || e.DATE :: DATE AS concant 
                          FROM   payment AS e 
                                 left join (SELECT id, 
                                                   alias 
                                            FROM   account) ac 
                                        ON ac.alias = e.account_alias 
                          WHERE  e.DATE :: DATE = (SELECT Min(e2.DATE :: DATE) 
                                                   FROM   payment AS e2 
                                                   WHERE 
                                 e2.account_alias = e.account_alias) 
                                 AND ac.id BETWEEN 600 AND 800) THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END 
FROM   (SELECT a.id              AS account_id, 
               p.account_alias, 
               SUM(p.amount)     AS amount, 
               p.DATE :: DATE    AS payment_date, 
               a.id 
               || '-' 
               || p.DATE :: DATE AS concant 
        FROM   payment p 
               left join (SELECT id, 
                                 alias 
                          FROM   account) a 
                      ON p.account_alias = a.alias 
        WHERE  a.id BETWEEN 600 AND 800 
        GROUP  BY a.id, 
                  p.account_alias, 
                  payment_date 
        ORDER  BY a.id, 
                  payment_date ASC) o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your repeated query (and thus the `IN` or `=`) isn't need at all.

To flag the first payment, you can calculate the the first date and use that to flag the row in the final select.

```
SELECT o.*, 
       o.payment_date = min_date as is_first_payment
FROM   (SELECT a.id              AS account_id, 
               p.account_alias, 
               SUM(p.amount)     AS amount, 
               p.date::date      AS payment_date, 
               min(p.date::date) over (partition by a.id, a.alias) as min_date
        FROM   payment p 
               left join account a 
                      ON p.account_alias = a.alias 
        WHERE  a.id BETWEEN 600 AND 800 
        GROUP  BY a.id, 
                  p.account_alias, 
                  payment_date 
        ORDER  BY a.id, 
                  payment_date ASC) o
```

Comment: Note that my query returns a `boolean` value, not a number for the flag

Comment: yep which is fine, as long as it is correct, I will use the true/no for the filter! thank you a ton!

Answer (score 0):

If you have more then a  result for subquery  then you could use IN instead of =

```
 CASE 
     WHEN o.concat IN  (SELECT DISTINCT ac.id 
                                      || '-' 
                                      || e.DATE :: DATE AS concant 
                      FROM   payment AS e 
                             left join (SELECT id, 
                                               alias 
                                        FROM   account) ac 
                                    ON ac.alias = e.account_alias 
                      WHERE  e.DATE :: DATE = (SELECT Min(e2.DATE :: DATE) 
                                               FROM   payment AS e2 
                                               WHERE 
                             e2.account_alias = e.account_alias) 
                             AND ac.id BETWEEN 600 AND 800) THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! tried and got 0s everywhere

Comment: @eponkratova additionally: I wouldn't use (or compare) concatenated values, but compare tuples of values instead. E.g. `when (account_id, payment_date) in (select distinct id, alias ...)`

Comment: @scaisEdge, can you, please, help me with ```SELECT DISTINCT ac.id, e.DATE :: DATE AS concant   FROM  payment AS e```? Because of distinct, I cannot put it as a tuple

Comment: silly of me, it is SELECT DISTINCT (ac.id, e.DATE :: DATE) AS concant

Comment: Now I got the error:operator does not exist: text = record
LINE 3:          WHEN o.concat = (SELECT DISTINCT (ac.id, e.DATE :: ...
                               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 50